# What is limiting my USB transfer rates?

Tags: linux, usb, hardware-failure, lenovo-laptop

I am trying to use three different sensors at the same time. One of the sensors is a Microsoft Kinect for Xbox One sensor (so technically two sensors) and the other two sensors are event-based cameras of type ATIS. All of the three sensors are connected to my Lenovo P51 Thinkpad via `USB 3.0` each on it's own USB port without a USB hub.
Now using the 2 ATIS sensors together yields no problem whatsoever. But when I launch the kinect sensor data transfer and then try to use one of the ATIS sensors, I get the following error

> Input/Output ErrorUSB Submit Error
>   submit Error in start

on my shell on Ubuntu 18.04. I think it is a libusb error.
So my assumption is, that my Mainboard (or other part of my hardware?) is not able to process information of 3 USB devices that all have a high data output fast enough. But I am not sure it's that, it's just my assumption.
So my questions are:
1. Is this presumably a hardware or a software problem?
2. If it's a hardware problem: Which part is limiting me and what would I have to look for, to replace it?

EDIT:
The output of `lsusb -t` is:

```
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/10p, 5000M  
    |__ Port 1: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/1p, 5000M  
        |__ Port 1: Dev 5, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=usbfs,   5000M  
        |__ Port 1: Dev 5, If 1, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=usbfs,     5000M  
        |__ Port 1: Dev 5, If 2, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 5000M  
        |__ Port 1: Dev 5, If 3, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 5000M
    |__ Port 5: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=usbfs, 5000M
    |__ Port 6: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=usbfs, 5000M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/16p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 12, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/1p, 480M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 9, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 11, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 11, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
        |__ Port 3: Dev 10, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 8: Dev 4, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 8: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 9: Dev 5, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=, 12M
    |__ Port 11: Dev 6, If 0, Class=Chip/SmartCard, Driver=, 12M
    |__ Port 13: Dev 7, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
    |__ Port 14: Dev 8, If 0, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
    |__ Port 14: Dev 8, If 1, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
```

Comment: Please connect all sensors and post output of `lsusb -t` ([edit] your question)

Comment: @gronostaj Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three of your ports are actually connected internally to a single USB 3.0 hub and share the USB 3.0 bandwidth.

To solve this issue you'd need a second USB 3.0 controller. You're probably using a laptop, so I'm afraid there's nothing you can do.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Yes, I am currently using a laptop, but this won't be an issue. If I know, what I am looking for, I can get access to other hardware. So for what specifications do I need to look? I guess it's something about the mainboard, isn't it?

Comment: Or is there maybe a loss-less USB-to-Thunderbolt adapter, so that I could use my thunderbolt port for one of the sensors? @gronostaj

Comment: And One more question: How do you read the output of `lsusb -t`? Everything that is `Class=Human Interface Device` is a physical USB port, right? And the ones with `Port 1: Dev 11` and `Port 3: Dev 10` are internally connected to `Port 2: Dev 9` and the `Port 13: Dev 7` one has its own hub?! Is this a common setup or is this some low quality/performance issue more typical for laptops? Do usual Computers have more than two hubs? EDIT: Sorry, for the multiple comments.

Comment: I don't know much about Thunderbolt and quick googling didn't return anything promising. With desktops you can always get a PCIe USB controller to get more bandwidth. Output of `lsusb -t` is a tree. You can see two top-level nodes with `Class=root_hub`, those are your internal hubs. There are two of them because one is for USB 3.0 (speed `5000M` at the end) and the other one for USB 2.0 and lower (speed `480M`), both share physical ports. Those `|__` thingies are ASCII art lines.

Comment: The first hub has three devices connected to it, one of which (probably Kinect) reports as another hub with four devices connected to it. _Human Interface Device_ (HID) are keyboards and mice. `1.5M` is USB 1.0 low speed, `12M` is USB 1.0 full speed. Laptops usually have the webcam internally connected to a USB bus, it's one (both?) of those `Class=Video` thingies.

Comment: Regarding those 3 devices on a single hub, that's not an unusual setup. Note that it's a USB 2.0 hub with bandwidth of 480 Mbps, but it hosts 3 USB 1.0 devices using total bandwidth of 15 Mbps, so there's plenty of headroom there. This trick is sometimes used to work around some limitations. For example some keyboards report as multiple keyboards on a hub to bypass the 6 keys per keyboard limit of BIOSes.

Comment: Ok, thanks for all the explanations. One final question: I just searched for an additional USB controller and found this for example: https://www.alternate.de/DeLOCK/PCI-Express-Karte-4x-USB-3-0-Controller/html/product/959407?event=search Now when I use this does it enable me to use all the 4 USB ports that it has with full USB 3.0 bandwidth?

Comment: I would guess the bandwidth is shared between those 4 ports, but I'm not sure.